# jQuery ionCalendar - how to set the first day of the week to monday

Tags: jquery, calendar

I am making a simple calendar using jQuery. I am absolute beginner in Java Script. I would like to change the "first day of the week" to monday, but nothing works (I searched through this page). Culd you please help me? I would like to know what and where should I write in my code to set the first day to monday.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="css/ion.calendar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

  <div id="demo1"></div>
  <div id="result-1">...</div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/ion.calendar.js"></script>

  <script>
    //( ".selector" ).datepicker({firstDay: 1});

    $(function() {
      $("#demo1").ionCalendar({
        lang: "sk",
        years: "2000-2050",
        firstDay: 1,
        onClick: function(date) {
          $("#result-1").html("onClick:<br/>" + date);
        }
      });
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `sundayFirst` setting to `false` as outlined in available [Settings](http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.calendar/en.html)

> An optional parameter that allows you to choose the first day of the week in the calendar. (For example in the U.S. week starts on Sunday in Russia on Monday). If true - then the first day will be Sunday, if false - it will be Monday.

```
$(function() {
  $("#demo1").ionCalendar({
    lang: "sk",
    years: "2000-2050",
    sundayFirst: false,
    firstDay: 1,
    onClick: function(date) {
      $("#result-1").html("onClick:<br/>" + date);
    }
  });
});
```